# What is good information to collect from anonymous users?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I've decided to collect technical information from anonymous users.'

My general plan is to collect the data in JavaScript, for example the user agent string, and ajax it to the server where I store it in a mysql table.

I plan to do this on each load of the application.

So the sql table would look something like this:

```
id
agent_string
ip address
hits
```

Becuase many people seem to visit the site but no sign up I want a reality check on how many people/machines visit my site.

Off the top of my head the only relevant info I can think of is agent_string ( to identify unique browsers ), the ip address ( to identify unique machines in a network ), ...

I realize there are lots of caveats but I'm not worried about those yet ( IP spoofing, agent string spoofing, etc. ) Just the big picture.

What are important things to collect from anonymous users.

Thanks

Comment: you realize that user agent and ip are trivially logged (or at least, CAN be logged) using a standard web server's access logs? there's no need for client-side code at all.

Comment: why re-invent the wheel? Companies like google (analytics) have put a _lot_ of thought in to this already (and track drop-offs, conversions, session time, etc.)

Comment: Moreover ip_address + User_agent does not uniquely identify a machine

Comment: Besides the user agent and the ip address are there any other parameters the client has, that might be useful?  I don't have access to the server logs, and I chose not to use GA that's why I posted the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the list you already gave, I would add the following from the top of my head:

- Window location - useful if you want to know how your users navigate inside your application;
- Window events and clicks - useful if you want to know how do your users navigate inside the page they are visiting (if they are using your table of contents, clicking in links for external sites, how long do they scroll, etc);
- Window size - useful for helping with dynamic CSS, specialy for mobile devices;

Keep in mind that, even if IP + Agent Strings aren't a unique ID from a user you could, at least, use a session ID that would allow for a complete track of your user in that session. Not bullet proof, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

install google analytics?  That way you can get location, referrers, exit pages, live action while they're browsing, unique visits, path people take etc.

Also... from a marketing standpoint, a very clear call to action is also essential.  The user needs to know what you want them to do or create a next step that is clear and obvious.

Comment: While google analytics is a great tool, there are many reasons why someone would not like to use it. E.g. if you don't want to expose the behavior of the own customers/visitors to a foreigner company.  Included the wrong way the performance of the site my suffer (I recognized frequent loading problems for ga or other resource delivered by foreign cdn).

Comment: you can track events of the user, and all the data mentioned above - it's not JUST good for marketing it's good for understanding user behavior, when they come when they go where your drop off points are, what they click (thus what they don't click) their technicaly info, screen size, operating system, browser, etc etc... not sure what you're specifically looking for but all of what you mention you can get from my suggestion.  OR your web host most likely has logs and stats installed already with most of the same data.